# 5D MkIII - how to maintain exposure (ratio) in M

Tags: canon, exposure

A quick question- is there a way of locking the exposure (EV) on 5D MkIII in Manual mode?

For instance, if I set my exposure to f/8 and 1/250, is there a way of going to f/4 and for the camera to go to 1/1000? (I mean from turning the main dial only?)

Thanks!

Comment: On some cameras, alas I don't think the 5D is one of them, you can press the AE-L button (Marked with a * IIRC) in M mode and turn the control-dial at the same time it will do as you say. Give it a try.

Comment: @Itai With the 5DIII that allows you to use the main dial to change Tv instead of Av or vice-versa (you can have the camera set up either way for M mode: Main dial changes Av, Quick Control dial changes Tv or you can set it up so that Main dial changes Tv, Quick Control Dial changes Av)

Comment: *Why* are you asking specifically about manual mode when the very purpose of that mode is to allow separate adjustment of aperture and shutter speed? What's your resistance to Av or Tv mode if you want to adjust those parameters together and maintain a particular EV? That's what those modes *do*.

Comment: @Caleb Tv and Av depend on the camera's metering to provide the "base" EV. There are times when the light in the scene is changing rapidly but one might wish to use a constant EV for all of one's shots even while swapping out the Av and Tv in reciprocal actions.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such functionality with the 5D Mark III.

The 7D Mark II and 5D Mark IV (and maybe other newer models) have something *almost* like what you're asking. If you 1) swap lenses to one with a narrower aperture, 2) add an extender (which raises the maximum f-number), or 3) use a zoom lens at a focal length that has a narrower maximum aperture than what the camera is set to in **Manual** exposure mode then the camera can alter either the shutter speed or ISO value to compensate. There is a custom function option that allows the user to disable the feature, use ISO to shift, or use Tv to shift.

With the 5D Mark III the closest you'll get is to use **Program** mode. To alter exposure you can use the *Quick Control Dial* on the back of the camera to set *Exposure Compensation*. You can lock in a particular EV by pressing the *AE Lock* button (the button next to the AF-ON button marked with an "*"). You can then shift Tv and Av in opposite directions by moving the *Main Dial* just behind the shutter button.

If you press and release the *AE Lock* button, as long as the viewfinder is active the camera will maintain the same EV as you shift through various combinations of Tv and Av. Once the viewfinder becomes inactive or you press the shutter button all the way down to take a picture the EV is reset the next time you initiate metering or AF to activate the viewfinder. You can also press and hold the *AE Lock* button to keep metering active and maintain the same EV indefinitely (or at least until the camera's battery is exhausted). The locked EV will be maintained for as many frames as you choose to take while holding the *AE Lock* button.

You can also choose one of several metering modes that may get the initial *Exposure Value* selected by the camera closer to what you want. *Spot*, *Partial*, and *Center weighted average* metering modes will move progressively from the smallest spot in the center of the frame to the largest area. *Evaluative Metering* uses a library of scenarios to determine which area of the frame should be neutrally exposed.

Comment: I was asking specifically about Manual mode!

Comment: The first sentence of the answer specifically answers that there is no such functionality for the 5DIII in Manual mode.

Answer (score 1):

P mode can achieve this to some (large) extent. The exposure is locked, but aperture and speed can still be adjusted. They cannot be adjusted independently. The overall exposures will stay the same.

To start with some exposure that's different from what the meter reading was, you'd have to do that with exposure compensation. This limits the overall exposure level that you can choose that it cannot be very far away from the meter reading, because exposure compensation is limited to some offset from the meter reading, usually +- 2 or 3 stops.

Comment: The 5D Mark III has the ability to use +/- 5-stops of exposure compensation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the camera to change the shutter automatically in relationship to the changes you make to the aperture then use the camera in aperture priority mode and the shutter will change automatically when you change the aperture. Or the inverse it true, if you want to use a specific shutter speed to stop motion then you would use shutter priority mode, choose the shutter speed and then if you decide that the speed you chose is not fast enough when you change to a faster speed the camera will compensate accordingly. In both cases if you use the exposure compensation ( say plus 1/3 stop ) the camera will maintain the setting of the mode you are in ( the aperture or the shutter ) and change the other to keep the exposure compensation you have set.

The point of being in manual mode is that your brain makes the decisions and you  control the camera. if you  know you made a two stop adjustment to the aperture  then you can quickly make a two stop adjustment to the shutter speed using the handy buttons at your fingertips.

Comment: Your answer assumes the brightness of the scene is constant. In **Av** and **Tv** mode if the brightness of the scene changes then the Tv or Av will change to compensate for the change in brightness.

Comment: the OP states "For instance, if I set my exposure to f/8 and 1/250, is there a way of going to f/4 and for the camera to go to 1/1000? (I mean from turning the main dial only?)   my answer addressed that.

Comment: But if you are half pressing the shutter and the scene brightness changes (depending on which metering mode you are using) you will no longer be at f/8 and 1/250 - you may be at f/8 and 1/1000 *before* you change the aperture to f/4 which will then put the Tv at 1/4000...

Answer (score 1):

> A quick question- is there a way of locking the exposure (EV) on 5D MkIII in Manual mode?

A quick answer: **No.**

The Av and Tv modes adjust shutter speed and aperture, respectively, to provide a proper exposure given your chosen aperture or shutter speed, respectively. And you can use exposure compensation to change the level that the camera considers "proper," but both these modes (and P mode as well) rely on the metering system. You seem to want to set some arbitrary combination of aperture and shutter speed and then lock them together, so that they change inversely, i.e. +1 stop of aperture would be compensated for with -1 stop of exposure time and vice versa. That's not a feature that's available on any mainstream camera that I know of.